# Is it possible to make this image using svg

Tags: html, svg

This is the image I want to make.

[image]

But this is my SVG codes

```html
    <svg class="teeth" id="svg"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="molar-group" class="molar">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="disto-occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="125" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <rect x="200" y="75" stroke="black" id="mesio-occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="125" height="150" fill="white"/>
    
            <polygon stroke="black" id="disto-buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 200 0 200 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesio-buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="200 0 400 0 325 75 200 75" fill="white" />
    
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="400 0 400 300 325 225 325 75" fill="white" />
    
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesio-palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="400 300 200 300 200 225 325 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="disto-palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="200 300 0 300 75 225 200 225" fill="white" />
    
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```

The output of my SVG codes is in the image below:

[image]

Can anyone help me with how to do the first image based on my SVG codes? 
The only missing in the second image is the X line can anyone help how to add the X line in the first image is it possible to do using SVG?

Comment: you don't want a CSS solution?

Comment: no sir, I want SVG because it easy to convert to base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only missing in the second image is the X line can anyone help how
>   to add the X line in the first image is it possible to do using SVG?

To add `X` to the image, simply add a couple more lines of`<polyline>`

```html
<svg class="teeth" id="svg"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="molar-group" class="molar">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="disto-occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="125" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <rect x="200" y="75" stroke="black" id="mesio-occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="125" height="150" fill="white"/>
    
            <polygon stroke="black" id="disto-buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 200 0 200 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesio-buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="200 0 400 0 325 75 200 75" fill="white" />
    
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="400 0 400 300 325 225 325 75" fill="white" />
    
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesio-palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="400 300 200 300 200 225 325 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="disto-palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="200 300 0 300 75 225 200 225" fill="white" />
    
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" /> 
                 <!-- Two lines added -->
   <polygon stroke="black" class="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="100 300  300 0" fill="white" /> 
    <polygon stroke="black" class="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300  100 0" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```